# Passing structures between functions

Tags: c, struct

I was trying to learn how structures are passed between functions and I wrote a program where there is an array of structure and structure itself has an array of integers.It is compiling properly but when I run it,the program is not expecting more than 4 values.I dont know what the error is?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 

typedef struct
{
    char bname[10];
    int ssn[3];
} book;

void accept(book k[], int n);
void print(book k[], int n);
int main()
{
    book a[2];
    accept(a, 2);
    print(a, 2);
    return 0;
}

void accept(book k[], int n)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d\n", &k[i].ssn[j]);
        }
        scanf("%s\n", k->bname);
    }
}

void print(book k[], int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)

    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\n", k[i].ssn[j]);
        }

        printf("%s\n", k->bname);
    }
}
```

Comment: Start with indenting your code.

Comment: `scanf("%d\n"`...are you sure you intend to have the `\n` there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `accept` function:

```
for (j = 0; j < 3; i++)     // infinite loop
```

Should be **j**++ .

Next, in both `accept` and `print` change `k->bname` to `k[i].bname`, so as not to rewrite always the first object.

And as already pointed out in comments by @SouravGhosh why use `scanf("%d\n"...` - it can be just `scanf("%d"...`.